# MySQL Average Date When Dates are Higher than 2038-01-19 (Can't Use UNIX_TIMESTAMP)

Tags: mysql

I need to find the average date in a MySQL DB column. The dates will be above 2038-01-19 so I cannot use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function. Does anyone know of a different way to get the average date?

Comment: I imagine that these questions will become more frequent over the next few years. :)

Comment: @Ted Hopp - Actually, I'd be pretty surprised it they become common before December 2037 ;-P

Comment: @Alvaro - Sadly, you are almost certainly right. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Instead of using the UNIX_TIMESTAMP I used TO_DAYS and FROM_DAYS and it seems to work as expected.

```
create table test (mydate date);
insert into test values ('2042-10-01'), ('2043-10-01'), ('2044-10-01');
mysql > SELECT FROM_DAYS(AVG(TO_DAYS(mydate))) FROM test;

+---------------------------------+
| FROM_DAYS(AVG(TO_DAYS(mydate))) |
+---------------------------------+
| 2043-10-01                      |
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `AVG` function?

```
create table test (mydate date);
insert into test values ('2042-10-01'), ('2043-10-01'), ('2044-10-01');

mysql> select avg(mydate) from test;
+-------------+
| avg(mydate) |
+-------------+
|    20431001 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: AVG is intended for a numeric argument (see [bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9874](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9874)). This doesn't work properly on date/time fields.